# Error inflating class : Android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-seekbar

I have issue in xml file for GUI in android. This is my second app, so not much sure why the error is appearing. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

The error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$400(VectorDrawable.java:204)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java:837)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.<init>(VectorDrawable.java:812)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.mutate(VectorDrawable.java:268)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:817)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:329)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable$AnimatedStateListState.addStateSet(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:602)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseItem(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:525)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:453)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:385)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:315)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:681)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:99)
at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:85)
at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:81)
at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:654)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:596)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:591)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Not sure what the issue is, i triad all the solutions already available on stackoverflow which says some issue with 9 patch image not updated properly but nothing helped. Note: this error only comes the moment I add seekbar control in xml.

Thanks

Ashutosh

Comment: changing the API version of the preview section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an issue and it is being handled by google [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216597):

Some other people are facing the same issue and the fix is always to change the preview API from 24 to 23 (or any other version).

You may need to download a previous version of SDK.. **You don't need to change your build.gradle**... Just download the SDK and Android Studio will allow you to change the SDK in Layout Preview

[image]